# Plurk API jSON Callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Good Day!

Who have tried Plurk API? I have a problem regarding JSON callback. I'm using $.getJSON by jquery to get public timeline of a user. The plurk supports JSON data. I need to implement JSONP for crossbrowsing problem, so i need to know the callback parameter of Plurk API if any? I already googled this but i found nothing.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Callback parameter is simply `callback` for a website that claims it supports JSON-P.

A quick test showed that Plurk API only supports JSON and it ignores the `callback` parameter.

Even if it supports JSON-P, you shouldn't use it for the purpose as it will expose your api key out in the wild.

Consider writing an server-side proxy for it.

Comment: Thanks...anyway i'm gonna try server-side scripting.